# How can I see schema for queries in pg_stat_activity?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to sort out some app performance issues with slow queries. We are using Postgresql 9.2. I can see the queries in progress easily:

```
postgres=# select now() - query_start, query from pg_stat_activity where state <> 'idle';

00:00:01.535388 | select bla from product where ...
```

I need to know what schema the tables listed in the query are in. How can I see which "product" table is being queried given that there are hundreds of them in different schemas in the same database.

Answer (score 1):

**pg_stat_activity** view calls **pg_stat_get_activity(pid int)** internal function. 
You have no chances to change query text in result.
There is only one solution for now - call your queries with schema names:

```
select bla from myschema.product where ...
```

Comment: hmm .. it it possible to discover the search_path for a pid?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Postgres documentation does not mention of such a possibility (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK If the query you are interested in has locks, you may find out its schema oid from **pg_locks** and then the schema name from **pg_namespace**.